# Unwanted space in text where float is positioned in the code

Tags: spacing, floats, white-space

I am new to Latex, so I hope I am using the correct vocabulary to describe my problem. I couldn't find an answer to it.

When I am including a figure in the code, it is displayed at a different location in the pdf file. That is okay. However, at the position where I originally placed the figure in the code, there is free space in the pdf file. I know that I could remove the free space using \vspace{}, but I think there has to be a better solution.

```
begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight,]{Images/values+scores.png}
    \caption{The scores of the PCA are plotted along the highest variance of the data}\label{fig:values+scores}
    \end{figure}    
\end{center}

As can be seen in figure \autoref{fig:values+scores} score 1 captures the highest variance of the data, while score 2 is orthogonal to score 1.

\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight,]{Images/PCs.png}
    \caption{True and noisy data points plotted in the rotated coordinate system}\label{fig:PCs}
    \end{figure}    
\end{center}
```

[image: This Image shows a part of the output pdf. I don't know why I am getting the free lines around the text and don't want them to show.]

The image above shows a part of the output pdf. I don't know why I am getting the free lines around the text and I don't want them to show.

The beginning of my document where I load my packages looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, parskip=full]{scrbook}  % coma Dokument-Klasse
  %\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % für 1 2 Bild benötigt
\usepackage[english]{babel} %selbst eingefügt, damit English geht
  %\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % Silbentrennung u.a.
  %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Zeichensatz mit deutschen Umlauten
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % uft8 text-Codierung
  \usepackage{graphicx}          % Anzeigen von JPG- und PDF-Grafiken
  \usepackage[                   % automatisches Erstellen von Verknüpfungen
               breaklinks=true,  % wird ein verknüpfter Text am Zeilenende umgebrochen, sind beide Hälften anklickbar
               pageanchor=true,  % jede Seite erhält ein Verknüpfungsziel, welches vom Index genutzt wird
               plainpages=false, % alle Verknüpfungsziele erhalten eindeutige Namen, indem die Formatierung berücksichtigt wird (z.B. "iv" und "4")
               pdfborder={0 0 0}   % der Kasten um Verknüpfungen hat Dicke 0 (letzter Parameter) und ist damit unsichtbar
             ]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{geometry}      % seiten und Ränder anpassen
  \geometry{a4paper,left=36mm,right=32mm, top=41mm, bottom=40mm} 
  \usepackage{makeidx}           % Erstellen eines Index
  \usepackage{url}               % sinnvolle Trennung von langen URLs
  \usepackage{lmodern}           % Vektorschriften
  \makeindex             % Erstellung eines Indices (optional)
  \usepackage{nomencl}           % Symbolverzeichnis
  \makenomenclature      % Symbolverzeichnis erstellen
  \usepackage{booktabs}      % schöne Tabellen
  \usepackage{amsmath}       % mathematische Erweiterungen
  \usepackage{amssymb}       % z.B. Mengensymbole
  \usepackage{amsthm}        % Zusammenfassen von Beispielen
  %\usepackage{subfig}         % Nebeneinanderstellen von Abbildungen, habe figure zu fig geändert
  %\usepackage{subfigure}
%  \usepackage[german]{algorithm2e}     % Pseudo-Codes (Deutsch)
  \usepackage{listings}      % Programmcode 
  \usepackage{ifthen}            % Fallunterscheidung fuer bedingtes uebersetzen
  \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     % Zeichnen in Latex
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz
  \usepackage{pgfplotstable}     % tabellen


\usepackage{caption} % Versuch
\usepackage{subcaption}     % Versuch, Packet für Unterschriften

\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing% Zeilenabstand 1,5
\usepackage{blindtext}%Blindtext

%\newsavebox{\measurebox} %selbst eingefügt  
  
\usepackage[%
backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}    % use style = numeric or alphabetic
\addbibresource{MA.bib}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}
     {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} % Bib Verzeichnis aus der Präsi übernommen.  
  
   %\newcommand{\BIBLanguage}{DEUTSCH}% Schalter Deutsches Literatur VZ
  \newcommand{\BIBLanguage}{ENGLISH}% Schalter Englisches Literatur VZ

%\ifthenelse{\equal{\BIBLanguage}{DEUTSCH}}{
 % \usepackage[square]{natbib}      % deutsches Literaturvz
%}
{
 \newcommand{\citep}[1]{\cite{#1}}
}

% Layout-Einstellungen
\widowpenalty = 10000             % keine "Hurenkinder"
\clubpenalty = 10000              % keine "Schusterjungen"
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000   % kein Seitenumbruch in Fussnoten
```

How can I stop latex from inserting these free lines? Help is very much appreciated, since I don't know what to do anymore :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe try with the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Don't put center environments around the figure.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the isue itself but please be aware that `hyperref` should generally (with just a few exceptions) be the last package you load in your preamble. Instead of `\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \includegraphics...` use the `\centering` command inside of the `figure` environment.

Comment: the `center` environments add vertical space before and after but the float floats away just remove the `center` environments.